# How do I print 4 numbers as a string in C?

Tags: c, string

I've written some code to generate 4 random numbers.

Can anyone help me use the same code but to print them as a string?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(void)
{
    int num, i;
    srand(time(NULL));  // Seed ONCE

    for(i=0; i<4; ++i) // Loop 4 times for random numbers
    {
        num = rand();
        num = num % 10;
        printf("%d\t", num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just so we're all clear, can you provide a concrete example of what you'd like the output to look like?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I keep forgetting how much I hate C strings (and they apparently don't play nice with me either). I'll let someone who is more of an expert answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your `for` loop with this. It prints 4 random digits as a string:

```
printf("%04d\n", rand()%10000);
```

Alternatively, if you want a resulting string, say `s`, that you can print or compare then:

```
char s[4+1];    
sprintf(s, "%04d", rand()%10000);
printf("%s\n", s);
```

As @anatolyg points out, here's a short way to embed those `\t` chars if you need them:

```
char s[4+1];    
sprintf(s, "%d\t%d\t%d\t%d", rand()%10, rand()%10, rand()%10, rand()%10)
printf("%s", s);
```

And the kitchen-sink answer...  If you want a string (`s`) when you're done AND you really need those embedded `\t` chars after each digit AND if you want some flexibility to change the number of digits needed, then here's one way.  There may be a shorter way to code this one, but I hope what it's doing is clear to you.  (Up top, drop a `#define DIGITS (4)` or whatever count you need.)

```
int bufsize = DIGITS*2+1;
char s[bufsize];
s[--bufsize] = 0;
while (bufsize) {
    s[--bufsize] = '\t';
    s[--bufsize] = '0'+rand()%10;
}
printf("%s", s);
```

Comment: how to i add a tab after each number?

Comment: You don't need the `04`, just `%d` will do the same thing

Comment: can I also compare another string with the answer?

Comment: @Smac89, that will not ensure 4 digits (i.e. leading 0s will be missed).

Comment: @DarrenStone To preserve style, you can use `sprintf(s, "%d\t%d\t%d\t%d", rand()%10, rand()%10, rand()%10, rand()%10)`

Comment: @anatolyg, yes, good point.  Wasn't sure if those embedded `\t` chars were essential. Your code would do it.  I'd probably throw a `#define RAND10 (rand()%10)` up top for that. :-)

Comment: the code that you provided me with works but it doesnt give me another random string digits. am I missing something?

Comment: @YannBohbot, please explain what you mean by "another random string digits".  Of the 4 code blocks above, the last three all give you a string of random digits (`s`).  You can then compare or print or re-use that string `s`.

Comment: figured it out thanks works great but can you explain me the in bufsize=4*2+1?

Comment: Sure, you need to allocate space for your string.  A number of bytes (chars).  You need a character for each digit (that's 4), plus a trailing `\t` tab digit after each (that makes it 4*2), then the terminating NULL char. That's 4*2+1. Hope this helps.

Comment: No sweat. If this is answered to your satisfaction, please mark it as such. Cheers.